# C# Refence or instance ( For List and assignment )

Tags: unity, c#

**First question :**

Does List holds the refence to an object or the instance itself ?

**Second question :**

When I assign an object to another, are they the same instance or two different ones ?

```
MyObjectType tempObject = realObject;
```

**Third question :**

When I assign a List to another List, are they same Lists or different ones ?

```
List<MyObjectType> tempList = realList;
tempList.Remove(someObject);
```

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is usually better for questions about programming. Also, I think best answer would be "try it". 1. does chaning value/property list[0] also change X on previously inserted object(try this for both List<object> and for  List<int> )? 2. What happens with the other if you change a field? 3. was someObject also removed from realList?

Comment: Yeah, I was so focused on my current problem that I clicked on the first stack link that showed up in my browser's history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A List holds a bunch of references.  In regards to C# from C++, basically every Reference-type (i.e. derived from class, NOT struct) is a "reference."
2. If they're classes, they are TWO REFERENCES to the same instance.
3. Again -- reference to the same List -- so the update you do will happen on both.  (realList will lose the item in it).

To give you a better understanding C#'s garbage collector looks to find when things are no longer referenced... i.e. you have a reference type that is no longer having a scope (i.e. it was declared and used in a method, but that method has exited the call stack) -- and if so, it marks it for garbage collection.  Now, if you return that reference type from a method, the method no longer has access to the local (so it would normally be marked for garbage collection), but the call stack one level down now has a reference to that object, so it will not be marked for collection.

I highly recommend looking at the GC for C# -- it might give you more perspective on what's going on under the covers.  It really cemented my understanding of these things.